# Probability of choosing at least 25 children when you pick 75 people, given that the probability of picking a child is 20%?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to solve this question:

> I am given that $20%$ of a population is children. If I randomly pick
>   75 people from the population, then what is the probability that at
>   least 1/3 of the 75 people are children?

**This is how I am attempting to solve the problem:**

The probability that exactly 1/3 of the 75 people are children is $(0.2)^{25}$. Since the question asks for "at least", I don't really care about the outcomes of the other picks (they are just $(1)^{50}$). So, can't I just multiply $(0.2)^{25} * (1)^{50}$ by $\binom{75}{25}$ to get the answer, since there are $\binom{75}{25}$ ways of ordering the picks?

Unfortunately, my "probability" is around 176, an impossible value.

What am I doing wrong and how do I solve this problem?

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned the population size $P$, I'm going to assume it's arbitrarily large so that picking one child does not change the probability that your next pick will also be a child (because 1 is so much smaller than $P$).

Let $X$ be the number of children picked.
Let $N$ be the total number of people chosen.

Here, clearly, $N=75$. We wish to find the probability $P(X \geq 25)$.

Basically this can be modeled as a Binomial random variable, provided my assumption above holds since that should imply the trials are basically independent.

Our number of trials is $N=75$. Each of these trials is either a 'success' (we choose a child) with probability $0.2$ or it's a failure (we choose an adult) with probability $1-0.2=0.8$.

Hence we see that $X \sim Binomial(75,0.2)$

You can then use your calculator to find that $P(X \geq 25) = 1- P(X < 25) = 1-0.9953 = 0.0047$ (rounded)

---

To explain why your reasoning is wrong:

Firstly since it says at least 25, you need to find $P(X=25)$, $P(X=26)$,...,$P(X=75)$ and sum them together. The binomial CDF on your calculator (or online) does this automatically.

Secondly your logic about how to find the probability is fundamentally wrong. I don't know where you got $1^{50}$ from, but that makes no sense. If you want to find the probability of getting 25 kids, and 50 adults then what you would do is this:

$P(X=25) = 0.2^{25} \times 0.8^{50} \times$ (number of ways this can happen)

You then do the same for $26$, $27$, etc... and sum them. This is **not** equal to $0.2^{25} \times 1^{50} \times$ (number of ways to pick at least 25 kids).

Comment: Extremely helpful, Patty! Wonderful explanation!